# How to use DynamoDB PartiQL with array attributes

Tags: typescript, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

I'm trying to use the aws sdk to insert a new record using the PartiQL api. Most attribute types work fine except when I try insert records that have array attributes. For example,

```js
import { DynamoDBClient, ExecuteStatementInput } from '@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb';
import { ExecuteStatementCommand } from '@aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb';

export const ddbClient = new DynamoDBClient({
  region: 'us-east-1',
});

let params: ExecuteStatementInput = {
  Statement: "INSERT INTO hardware_request VALUES {'requestId': ?,'reasonId': ?,'status': ?,'requesterId': ?,'createdAt': ?,'updatedAt': ?,'approverId': ?,'dateApproved': ?,'approverComments': ?,'requesterComments': ?,'equipmentIds': ?,",
  Parameters: [
    { S: 'd1296fcb-6cfb-4878-93de-4ab97fa9e475' },
    { S: '1' },
    { S: 'PENDING' },
    { N: '1' },
    { N: '1' },
    { N: '1' },
    { N: '3' },
    { N: '1' },
    { S: 'string' },
    { S: 'pls work' },
    {
      NS: [
        '11',
        '12',
      ],
    },
  ],
};

let run = async() => {
  let result = await ddbClient.send(new ExecuteStatementCommand(params));
  console.log(result);
};

run().then(() => console.log('sucesss')).catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This is the stack trace:

```
TypeError: input.filter is not a function
    at serializeAws_json1_0NumberSetAttributeValue (/Volumes/workplace/AtricaPublishedAppExample/src/AtricaPublishedAppExample/node/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:3898:10)
    at Object.NS (/Volumes/workplace/AtricaPublishedAppExample/src/AtricaPublishedAppExample/node/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:3189:31)
    at Object.AttributeValue.visit (/Volumes/workplace/AtricaPublishedAppExample/src/AtricaPublishedAppExample/node/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/models/models_0.js:490:28)
    at serializeAws_json1_0AttributeValue (/Volumes/workplace/AtricaPublishedAppExample/src/AtricaPublishedAppExample/node/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:3182:38)
    at /Volumes/workplace/AtricaPublishedAppExample/src/AtricaPublishedAppExample/node/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:3934:16
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at serializeAws_json1_0PreparedStatementParameters (/Volumes/workplace/AtricaPublishedAppExample/src/AtricaPublishedAppExample/node/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:3933:10)
    at serializeAws_json1_0ExecuteStatementInput (/Volumes/workplace/AtricaPublishedAppExample/src/AtricaPublishedAppExample/node/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:3539:25)
    at serializeAws_json1_0ExecuteStatementCommand (/Volumes/workplace/AtricaPublishedAppExample/src/AtricaPublishedAppExample/node/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/protocols/Aws_json1_0.js:257:27)
    at serialize (/Volumes/workplace/AtricaPublishedAppExample/src/AtricaPublishedAppExample/node/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-dynamodb/dist-cjs/commands/ExecuteStatementCommand.js:30:78)
```

I've stepped through the aws code and I can see that the array attribute gets converted from {"NS": ["11", "12"]} to {"NS": "L": ["11", "12"]} by some internal marshaller. It seems to me that the marshaller has a bug but maybe I'm passing in the wrong information.

Has anyone successfully inserted a record with array attributes using PartiQL statement and parameters? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is related to the imports. The ExecuteStatementCommand should be imported from @aws-sdk/client-dynamodb not aws-sdk/lib-dynamodb. The reference I included imported it correctly so this is completely user error.